# What is this || notation in BIP 341?

Tags: hash, taproot, bip

`SHA256(SHA256(tag) || SHA256(tag) || x)`

What is the `||` notation? Is this the conjunction of the different elements? Bitwise OR? or modulus?

Answer (score 5):

The meaning of the two pipes is explained in [BIP340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki#specification):

> || refers to byte array concatenation.

The tags for the various tree elements are repeated to amount to 64 bytes. The doubling [allows the first step of the outer SHA256 hash to be pre-computed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/108087/5406) as sha256 processes the input in 64 byte-chunks.